# dict type numpy.AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, python-3.6, indexoutofboundsexception

I am not able to figure out how to fix this error when I run my python code. This is the entire error

```
Loading all_data
type of alldata <class 'dict'>
Sorting these keys dict_keys([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 48, in <module>
    keys_sorted = np.sort(all_data.keys())
  File "/home/MAHEUNIX/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 934, in sort
    a.sort(axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
numpy.AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
MAHEUNIX@WGSHA-LAB-005:/
```

This is the  corresponding code code:

```
print("Loading all_data")
all_data = load_dataset()
print("type of alldata",type(all_data),"\n")

print ("Sorting these keys", all_data.keys(),"\n\n")
keys_sorted = np.sort(all_data.keys())
print("keys sorted successfully\n")

train_idx, valid_idx = train_test_split(all_data.keys(), train_size = 0.9)
print (train_idx)
```

What is happening?

Comment: In py3, you need to use `list(adict.keys())` to get a list of keys.  `np.sort(keys())` makes 0d scalar array from the `keys()` iterable, hance the indexing error.

Comment: Thanks! It's working I think. Replaced  `all_data.keys()` with sorted(keys) is this right?

Comment: by adict, do you mean all_data?